# Restoring a volume from backup using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I've been trying to accomplish migrating a volume from one container to the same container on a different host, just by testing out the method in the [Docker docs: Restore Volume from Backup](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#restore-volume-from-backup). However, the project I am working on starts the container using `docker-compose` instead of `docker run`. Anyone know if I can change the .yaml file somehow to decompress a tarball (similar to the docker run method)?

The `docker run` command for restoring from a backup looks like this:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I followed the docs linked in my question. The reason it wasn't working originally is because I needed to double check that the original volume AND container were removed before mounting the backup volume.

Essentially,

1. Backup volume as per the Docker documentation
2. Remove original container and volume
3. Restore volume as per documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you can decompress the tarball file you can use this in your docker-compose.yaml file

```
 mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      hostname: mysql
      container_name: mysql
      restart: always
      expose:
          - '3306'
      ports:
          - '3306:3306'
      environment:
          - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=something'
      volumes:
          - mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./your-backup.sql-file:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've had to move on to other tasks now, but will try it out as soon as I'm able. I appreciate the help! I was hoping to be able to untar the backup using docker-compose somehow, but I can achieve these two steps using a shell script.